# Xcode 7.3 and iCloud Drive

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode7, icloud-drive

I just update Xcode 7.2 to 7.3. My app fetch and store files on icloud drive. If I run app on real device it works fine, if I run in the simulator (logged with my icloud account) the metadataQueryResults returns always 0 files.

Also the system app "iCloud Drive" cannot fetch or save icloud folders and files.

I tried Debug-->Trigger iCloud sync with no luck.

With xcode 7.2 and any simulator running iOS 8.x or greater worked fine.

Is it a xcode 7.3 bug?

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with OS X 10.11.4.  Stay at OS X 10.11.3 or use the 10.11.5 beta.

Answer (score -1):

Yes I got the same problem too after getting the latest Xcode 7.2 -> 7.3.
It looks like a problem with Apples background services crashing in the simulator and not telling its client i.e. the iCloud Drive or your app.
Even triggering an iCloud re-sync doesn't sort it so for the time being we have to debug on a real device which is a pain.

Looking in the system log via the simulator (Debug -> Open System Log), I see a lot of Sandbox (bird) access denied messages from the simulator which I guess are related to the issue - there is more info in some e.g.:

Process:         bird [597]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CloudDocsDaemon.framework/bird
Load Address:    0x1085b8000
Identifier:      bird
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       x86_64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd_sim [566]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2016-04-07 08:28:45.714 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.11.4 (15E65)
Report Version:  8

Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000010aae21fa openbyid_np + 10
1   CloudDocsDaemon                 0x00000001086f0664 -[BRCRelativePath _resolveAndKeepOpenMustExist:error:] + 872
etc.

I guess there are some permissions that have not been set on the file system that is used on the Mac backend for the simulator, but I've no idea how or what to change.

Do you get the same errors in your log when trying to use iCloud?

The only other thing I did recently was to install the latest Xamarin Studio, I hope that's not related but I doubt it.

Thanks
Matt

Comment: Now is working. I made lot of test and cannot tell which one fixed, but this is what I did: Upgraded to OS X 10.11.5 beta, disabled my app icloud drive on all devices (settings-->icloud-->drive->set OFF for my app). Deleted app on all my devices (iphones and ipads), disabled icloud drive on my mac (the one I use to devel), deleted the folder ~/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~app.bundle.identifier. Maybe you can try all other actions before upgrade to 10.11.5 beta. Max